# Why are some contacts missing in some views after an android update followed by restoring the contacts?

Tags: contacts, updates, restore

Here is what happened: I upgraded my android version (to 2.1 on an Xperia X10 ), restored my contacts using the native apps. Some contacts are missing, but when I look at speed dial I can see some of the contacts. For example, I have contacts ABC and AYH: I see only AYH in phonebook but when I look at speed dials I see ABC also. I don t understand why is this happening. Am I, by any chance, not using an option to display all my contacts in phone book?

Comment: When you login to your Gmail account - are both contacts visible / included? (Assuming you do sync)

Comment: Sparx it seems i cannot find the reply button (if there is one) so i am going to post as an answer: i do not use a linked gmail account, i am very reluctant to give a 3rd party, especially google, data which i consider private

Comment: You're not alone, but that also means that you can't leverage some of the plus points of the Android system.

Comment: In your Contacts / People app, press MENU and see if there is a DISPLAY OPTIONS button which in other Android devices allows a user to specify which groups are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Go into your contacts Tab.

Press Menu > Display Options

You can then select 'Display only contacts with phones'

Also There is a list of accounts with 'Choose contacts to display' above it.

If you select each one of these you can choose which groups to hide or show, this may be were the numbers are being hidden.

---

Also within your text messaging app, you can press:

Menu > Settings and there is a setting that says 'Only mobile numbers'

deselect this as sometimes it hides numbers thinking they're not phone numbers when they are!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution for this problem. Follow these steps:

1. Backup all your contacts
2. open AppManager and goto "ALL" tab
3. search for this app "CONTACTS STORAGE" and clear its data
4. reboot device
5. restore your contacts...

Done.