# Some Android contacts with phone numbers are missing after update

Tags: contacts, hardware

After I updated my Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro from Gingerbread to ICS some of my contacts went missing. The strange thing is when these people call me, the phone recognizes them and displays their name, but I still can't view the contact. When I touch-and-hold on a name in the call log and choose "View contact" nothing happens. Touching once though calls them right away.

Also in the contacts list ("Contacts with phone numbers" is checked), where the rest of my contacts are listed, nothing happens when I touch a name. It should open up the contact. So now I can only call people who are in the call log.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are the "ghost" contacts present in your Google contacts? Do you sync your contacts to Google at all?

Comment: Hm, we had that issue before... Looks like [Why are some contacts missing in some views after an android update followed by restoring the contacts?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/10062/16575)

Comment: @bigbadonk420 I do sync Google Contacts, and no they are not visible there.